# SE37 CSAP_MAT_BOM_READ runtime error during CONVERT_MATNR_TO_INTERN_FORMAT

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I use se37 to test the FM `CSAP_MAT_BOM_READ` and just put in a material number and mark the field BOM_USAGE with a "X".

After excecuting it, I get the following runtime error:

> Error in the ABAP Application Program
>
> The current ABAP program "CSAP_MAT_BOM_READ=============FT" had to be
> terminated because it has come across a statement that unfortunately
> cannot be executed. In include "LCSAPU17", in line 81 of program  "SAPLCSAP",
> the following syntax errors have occurred: In PERFORM or CALL FUNCTION
> "CONVERT_MATNR_TO_INTERN_FORMAT", the actual parameter "MATERIAL" is
> incompatible with the formal parameter "I_MATNR".
>
> Author and last person to change the include are: Author         SAP
> Last changed by "SAP         "
>
> ...
>
> The following syntax error has occurred in program SAPLCSAP:
>
> In PERFORM or CALL FUNCTION "CONVERT_MATNR_TO_INTERN_FORMAT", the
> actual parameter "MATERIAL" is incompatible with the formal parameter
> "I_MATNR".
>
> " "

Can anyone tell me whats wrong here?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

Note 1940837 was installed to our SAP System.

Answer (score 0):

Like the short dump suggested, your parameters are not compatible. Check types of the import parameter in SE37 CSAP_MAT_BOM_READ and the parameter passed to the form "CONVERT_MATNR_TO_INTERN_FORMAT".

On my dev system

- SAP_BASIS 731    0013
- SAP_ABA  731 0013

both parameters belongs to csap_mbom-matnr.

There are several notes on service.sap.com/notes regarding this issue. Maybe there are one of those notes missing in your system.

Comment: I tried several methods to call this FM, I read qall OSS notes, but nothing. Thing I will report it to SAP, maybe they got an idea. Thanks so far.

Comment: Have you checked if all notes are installed using the notes browser in transaction SNOTES? Sometimes, the notes description differ from the correction instructions, so implenting all regarding notes may help out.